# c++ что это за параметр в void foo(int&& a)?

Tags: c++, функции

что это за параметр?
в чем его смысл?
что он может?
в общем объясните все

```c++
            || |
            || |
            VV V
void foo(int&& a);
```

Comment: [Краткое введение в rvalue-ссылки](https://habr.com/ru/post/226229/)

Comment: @AlexGlebe все понятно. спасибо